# My dogs lips and gums are changing color

Tags: dogs, health, veterinarian

I have a 1 and a half year old Male Rhodesian Ridgeback and in the past 2 months his lip and gum is changing color from black to a whitish-red. I have taken him to his vet but the vet just said it's pigmentation. I am not sure about that and am considering a second opinion from another vet. It just doesn't look right. I have read articles which suggest taking away rubber/plastic toys and bowls which I have done for the past week.

Please see the below picture

Now

[image]

Before(approximately 4 months ago)

[image]

Has anyone had this with their dogs or have any suggestions?

Comment: snout looks swollen too,allergy?

Comment: I have arranged to take him to another vet tomorrow. Hoping to have some news. If it is an allergy then I'm not really sure what he is allergic too. He was on grain free food which didn't work and I have seen a lot of problems with those diets. Possibly a hypo-allergenic food may work. Also like I said I removed plastic/rubber toys.

Comment: Thanks, but the jowls hang differently when a dog is upright as compared with laying down.... thanks though. If the swelling is obvious (in person), consider a possible bug bite, or bee sting(?).

Comment: Related non-dupe [My dog's gum, is it normal or not?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6394/13)

Comment: So the vet has suggested to remove my dogs stainless steel bowls as a precaution as some dogs have nickel allergy. Also we re trying something called happy liver for dogs by TCVM, as this helps restore liver balances and itchiness which my dogs does have. I will update as we go along.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely does not look a pigmentation due to the swelling. What your original veterinarian suggested would be vitiligo, which is gradual and does not generally happen within a week. My best guess would be that it is an allergy because of the swelling, I would get a second opinion on it from another veterinarian.